# Configuring C3P0 in Persistence.xml with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

Well, i'm trying to configure for first time the C3P0 with JPA + Hibernate + Spring. In persistence.xml i have:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
        value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />

    <!-- Important -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
        value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />
</properties>
```

But when i try to initialize the tomcat, i got the following error:

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 58 more
50570 [Thread-4] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - could not complete schema update
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
```

EDIT 1:

This is my applicationContext.xml, how can i configure C3P0 inside this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Seta anotaçoes para serem usadas pelo Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Define o pacote onde o Spring vai procurar por beans anotados -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.myapp" />

    <!-- define que as transaçoes irao ser anotadas -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

    <!-- Configuracao do Banco de Dados -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="pgadmin" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="senderPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: where are you configuring the JDBC url, username, and password of your database? (the problem is, as the Exception says, the pool did not succeed at acquiring Connections from the database. AFAICT, you've not told it where to look.)

Comment: Im using applicationContext.xml to configure it.

Comment: Post some additional configuration, the `applicationContext.xml`. If you have configured the datasource in the `applicationContext.xml` (as you mentioned) your `hibernate.c3p0` settings are pretty much useless as the configuration in the applicationcontext.xml takes precendence over this one.

Comment: I edited my post with content of applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your configuration is flawed. You are configuring the `DataSource` in the application context. So basically all `hibernate.c3po` properties are useless, next to that the setting of the `hibernate.connection.provider_class` property breaks your application. The `C3P0ConnectionProvider` expects a C3P0 Connection however you are using a basic `DriverManagerDataSource`.

I would suggest instead of trying to get hibernate to manage the pool simply configure it inside your applicationcontext. Replace your datasource definition with the following

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase" />
    <property name="user" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="pgadmin" />
    <!-- Pool properties -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="50" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
    <property name="loginTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>
```

And remove the `hibernate.c3p0` and `hibernate.connection.provider_class` from your persistence.xml. Added advantage of moving the configuration to Spring is that you could use a properties file to contain your properties and have them replaced by a `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` instead of having them fixed in your persistence.xml

Basically you could remove all your properties from the persistence.xml and move them to the spring based configuration.

2 other, non, related suggestions. You can remove `<context:annotation-config />` that is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`. It is recommended to use versionless xsd files in your header, so I would suggest removing the versions.

Comment: I changed to applicationContext.xml as you showed, but i got the following error: Invalid property 'driverClassName' of bean class [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource]: Bean property 'driverClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.

Comment: Oops my bad, must be `driverClass`, modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks now it's work. I already marked your answer as "SOlution"

Comment: Hi sir, can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009444/configure-c3p0-in-persistence-xml