# Spring Batch with Jpa Repository

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and tried using Spring Data Jpa. Seems that persisting the object using the CrudReposity opens the Db Connection for every record hurting the performance of the project.

Planning to move to spring jdbc with native query to improve the performance.Any suggestions?

Comment: You should setup a connection pool, such as C3P0. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23554873/configuring-c3p0-in-persistence-xml-with-jpa-and-hibernate

Comment: Hi Fabio, i have setup the connection pool but the pool gets exhausted after running for 30 mins. Seems that connections not returned back to the pool. i am planning to open single connection (Long session) and do the commits in batch and close the connection.

Comment: Planning to open single connection (Long session) and do the commits in batch and close the connection.                                                                       Cons: Have to reprocess again in case of connectivity loss

Comment: Are you closing your connections at all? Usually in the finally block.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I am not programatically opening and closing the connection since i am using the jpa repository. Do i need to open/close explicitly in the code?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38672900/how-to-manage-database-connection-pool-in-spring-jpa

Comment: Please share your job configuration as well as relevant parameters (connection pool size, thread pool size, etc). Are you using a multi-threaded step?

Comment: I created a demo project you can play with here: https://github.com/benas/sandbox/tree/master/so52083237. Try changing different parameters and see how it behaves. The p6spy log file shows that connections are reused (no resource leak), that one db connection is used for the entire chunk and not per record and that the connection pool is not exhausted even if there are more threads acquiring connections than the connexion pool size. Hope this helps in your performance issue investigation.